# laravel can't execute another request if current request isn't completed

Tags: laravel

I can't make another request if current request isn't completed.
if current request doesn't completed, all request are keep pending.
request should run in multiples in a time. please help and advise. I use Laravel 10.10, php 8.1 with sql server 2012R2 on windows 11 pro.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You're facing this problem because `php artisan serve` uses the built-in PHP server, and the built-in PHP server is single-threaded which means that it can execute only one request per time. If the server receives multiple requests, all of them will be blocked until the executing request is finished.

However, if you're on Linux, you can use the `PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS` environment variable to spawn multiple PHP workers, for example:

```
PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS=4 php artisan serve
```

This spawns 4 processes that run the `php artisan serve` command, and when a request blocks one worker the other 3 will still be available without getting blocked.

Please keep in mind that the built-in PHP server is only meant for development and testing purposes. Production environments require different sets of configurations.

You can learn more here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php